# Проблемы с монетизацией

Tags: unity3d, ads

Я пишу игру на юнити, хочу прикрутить монетизацию. По понятным причинам, решил использовать уже готовые `unity ads`. Установил плагин, выходит куча ошибок компиляции, вот такого типа:

```
Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ads@3.4.4/Runtime/Monetization/AndroidPlacementContentOperations.cs(55,40): error CS0433: The type 'IUnityLifecycleManager' exists in both 'UnityEngine.Advertisements.Editor, Version=3.4.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEngine.Advertisements, Version=3.4.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

Есть какие-то мысли, на этот счет?

Comment: обновить адс до 3.4.6 ? Исправление ошибок:
Отказ GooglePlayStore из-за небезопасного SSL

Comment: т.е. мне необходимо перейти на google ads?

Comment: не переходить, а попробовать обновить всё до последней версии. не зряже в ошибках написано

Comment: ну,плагин вроде как последней версии

Comment: установил буквально минут 15 назад, что еще необходимо обновить?

Comment: все, спасибо тебе. Я просто не правильно удалил плагин в прошлый раз, и некоторые временные файлы с версии 3.4.4 остались, потому и конфликт. Я их удалил, и переимпортировал плагин, все заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что некоторые остаточные файлы с плагина версии 3.4.4 не переимпортировались при переустановке новой версии 3.4.6